# Unable to display ordered items from users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following models:

product.rb

```
class Product

has_many :purchases
has_many :line_items
has_many :orders, :through => :order_products
```

lineitem.rb

```
class LineItem

belongs_to :product
belongs_to :cart
belongs_to: order
```

order.rb

```
class Order

belongs_to :user
belongs_to :product
has_many :purchases
has_many :line_items, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :orders, :through => :order_products
```

purchase.rb

```
class Purchase

belongs_to :order
belongs_to :product
```

**updated:**

order_product.rb

```
class OrderProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :order
    belongs_to :product
end
```

order_controller.rb

```
if @order.save

  if @order.purchase
    Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
    session[:cart_id] = nil
```

The above are my association for the models. However I face problems in displaying the products from a user. When the items are successfully purchased, the line_items are destroyed.

Does anyone know how do I store all the purchased items into purchase or any other better methods for me to display the products bought by a user?

I initially tried to retrieve line_items and it works. However, after the line_items are destroyed, I am not able to retrieve the relevant products.

Appreciate any help here.

Comment: can you show more of your `order` class?  why are line_items being destroyed?  or is your order being destroyed after it's completed?

Comment: Hi, i have updated my order controller. like most applications the line_items would be destroyed after payment has been successfully made. I am now trying to retrieve the products being placed by users after the payment has been made.

Comment: Use an act_as_paranoid gem of your choice https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_Soft_Delete

Comment: May I know how does the gem helps as I am currently considering to shift all the data to another model. Do you have any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try making an `order_history` for each user -

`user.rb`

```
def order_history
  #set this up according to how your models are related, etc  
  #with the idea being to call @user.order_history and getting an array of previous orders  
end
```

and then in `order_controller.rb`

```
if @order.save

      if @order.purchase
        #adapt this pseudocode to suit your needs and 
        #according to how you've defined `@user.order_history
        current_user.order_history = current_user.order_history + @order.line_items
        Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
        session[:cart_id] = nil
```

Essentially, push the `line_items` elsewhere so you have a record of them before you destroy the cart.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! However, do you happen to know of any elegant method to store this data into another model?

Comment: just replace the code under `if @order.purchase` with code to store the data in said model rather than in @user.

Comment: Hi there, I have added an additional table named order_products. However, is it possible to guide me on how to pass the line_items into the new model? Thanks

Comment: depending on how you've set it up, something like `if @order.purchase current_user.order_products.new(@order.line_items)`

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, it states undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass

Comment: that's why i said 'depending on how you've set it up' :)  does order_products belong to user?  if this answer helped, please mark it as accepted and/or upvote, and try to solve the next problem (about `order_products`) - if you can't get it, then open a new question.  the rule of thumb is one question per question

Comment: Hi there, I have accepted the answer. However, could I ask you more about it here? I have not link order_products to user. Do i need to? How do I assign order_id and product_id to order_products?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association association.

```
 User
   has_many :orders
   has_many :products, through: :orders

 Order
   has_many :line_items
   has_many :products, through: :line_items
```

Comment: Hi there, I am still unable to retrieve as line_items would be destroyed after payment has been made successfully.

Comment: You could add column to line_items model, with statuses like "pending", "processed", etc. Then add condition to relation, something like: `has_many :processed_products`, :through: :line_items, conditions: { 'line_items.status': 'processed'}, class_name: 'Product'. It will allow you to keep history and track everything.

Comment: Hi there, I have added an additional table named order_products. However, is it possible to guide me on how to pass the line_items into the new model? Thanks